# Number of nodes required based on query hits

Tags: search, elasticsearch, solr

If we get 1000 hits/s then,
How many nodes are required in elastic-search for a single complex query with aggregation.

Comment: Anywhere between one and infinity. The query profile, the number of documents, the performance of the hardware, the version of the server software, the aggregations performed, what the queries look like, etc. Test it and measure it.

Comment: yeah try doing a search load test.